# CircleCiでのRailsテスト実行時ランダムにエラーが発生してしまいます: ActionView::Template::Error: 783: unexpected token at ''

Tags: ruby-on-rails, テスト, circleci

ローカル環境では `rails test` が成功するのですが、GitHubにpushしてCircleCiのテスト中に高確率でエラーが発生してしまいます。ですが何回かリトライしてるとエラーが発生せずにテストが成功することもあります。
何が原因でこのような状態になっているのでしょうか？

また、同じテスト内容でもリトライするごとにエラーの発生箇所が変わったりもします。

Railsのテストコード自体はしっかりしたものなのに、CircleCiでのテストでのみエラーがランダムに発生してしまい時間がかかって困っています。

**エラー内容の例1**

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
bundle exec rails test
Running via Spring preloader in process 269
Started with run options --seed 53502

ERROR["test_invalid_signup_information", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x0000560b6b9513d0 @name="UsersSignupTest">, 10.051366892999795][0m==========         ] 76% Time: 00:00:10,  ETA: 00:00:03
 test_invalid_signup_information#UsersSignupTest (10.05s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: 783: unexpected token at ''
            app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9
            app/controllers/users_controller.rb:18:in `create'
            test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
            test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'

ERROR["test_login_with_valid_information", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x0000560b6b75f3d8 @name="UsersLoginTest">, 10.13947368600202][0m==========         ] 76% Time: 00:00:10,  ETA: 00:00:03
 test_login_with_valid_information#UsersLoginTest (10.14s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: 783: unexpected token at ''
            app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9
            test/integration/users_login_test.rb:24:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'

  21/21: [=================================] 100% Time: 00:00:10, Time: 00:00:10

Finished in 10.41909s
21 tests, 44 assertions, 0 failures, 2 errors, 0 skips

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

**エラー内容の例2**

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
bundle exec rails test
Running via Spring preloader in process 252
Started with run options --seed 40275

ERROR["test_login_with_valid_email/invalid_password", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x000055f679eeb658 @name="UsersLoginTest">, 17.182131017001666]m===               ] 57% Time: 00:00:00,  ETA: 00:00:00
 test_login_with_valid_email/invalid_password#UsersLoginTest (17.18s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: 783: unexpected token at ''
            app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9
            test/integration/users_login_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'

  21/21: [=================================] 100% Time: 00:00:17, Time: 00:00:17

Finished in 17.58606s
21 tests, 56 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

---

#### ソースコード

src/Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.4'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.5'
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '~> 1.0.4'
  gem 'minitest',                 '~> 5.11.3'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '~> 1.3.8'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - ./src/db/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: パスワード
  web:
    build: .
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7

ENV RAILS_ENV=production

RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
  && apt-get update -qq \
  && apt-get install -y nodejs yarn
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./src /app
RUN bundle config --local set path 'vendor/bundle' \
  && bundle install -j4

COPY start.sh /start.sh
RUN chmod 744 /start.sh
CMD ["sh", "/start.sh"]
```

start.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "${RAILS_ENV}" = "production" ]
then
    bundle exec rails assets:precompile
fi

bundle exec rails s -p ${PORT:-3000} -b 0.0.0.0
```

.circleci/config.yml

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  ruby: circleci/ruby@1.1.2
  heroku: circleci/heroku@1.2.3

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.7-node
    working_directory: ~/プロジェクトフォルダ名/src
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/プロジェクトフォルダ名
      - ruby/install-deps

  test:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.7-node
      - image: circleci/mysql:5.5
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: パスワード
          MYSQL_DATABASE: app_test
          MYSQL_USER: root
    environment:
      BUNDLE_JOBS: "3"
      BUNDLE_RETRY: "3"
      APP_DATABASE_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
      RAILS_ENV: test
    working_directory: ~/プロジェクトフォルダ名/src
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/プロジェクトフォルダ名
      - ruby/install-deps
      - run:
          name: Database setup
          command: bundle exec rails db:migrate
      - run: yarn install
      - run:
          name: test
          command: bundle exec rails test

  deploy:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.7-node
    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker:
          version: 19.03.13
      - heroku/install
      - run:
          name: heroku login
          command: heroku container:login
      - run:
          name: push docker image
          command: heroku container:push web -a $HEROKU_APP_NAME
      - run:
          name: release docker image
          command: heroku container:release web -a $HEROKU_APP_NAME
      - run:
          name: database setup
          command: heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production -a $HEROKU_APP_NAME

workflows:
  version: 2
  build_test_and_deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - test:
          requires:
            - build
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - test
          filters:
            branches:
              only: main
```

src/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>

  <% #ヘッダー▼ %>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  <% #ヘッダー▲ %>

    <% #コンテンツ▼ %>
    <main>
      <article class="contents">
        <%= yield %>
      </article>
    </main>
    <% #コンテンツ▲ %>

    <% #フッター▼ %>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    <% #フッター▲ %>

    <% #ドロワー▼ %>
    <%= render 'layouts/drawer' %>
    <% #ドロワー▲ %>

    <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>

  </body>
</html>
```

src/test/integration/users_signup_test.rb

```
require "test_helper"

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  #無効なアカウント作成のテスト
  test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    #users_pathへ無効な情報でPostリクエストを送ってもデータベースの数が増えてないことを確認
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post users_path, params: { user: { name:  "",
                                         email: "user@invalid",
                                         password:              "foo",
                                         password_confirmation: "bar" } }
    end
    assert_template 'users/new'
    #エラーメッセージが表示されていることを確認
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    assert_select 'div.alert_danger'
  end

  test "valid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post users_path, params: { user: { name:  "Example User",
                                         email: "user@example.com",
                                         password:              "password",
                                         password_confirmation: "password" } }
    end
    # follow_redirect!
    # assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_redirected_to root_path
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert is_logged_in?
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

このエラーの原因の一端は [webpacker](https://railsguides.jp/webpacker.html) です。私の知る限り未解決で、関連する issue はこの回答が書かれた時点で open のままです: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2860。

具体的には、アセットのコンパイルが行われていない状態でテストが並列に走る際に、webpacker がレースコンディションに陥っているのだと思われます。手元でテストを走らせた際にエラーが起こらなかったのは、ローカル環境にコンパイル済みのファイルがあるか、テストが並列になっていないかしたためでしょう。

webpacker 側で対処が行われるまでの間、以下のいずれかのワークアラウンドで対処できるはずです。

- test 環境でもテスト前に `assets:precompile` する、もしくは、
- Webpacker の利用をやめる。

なお、英語版 Stack Overflow にも同様の Q&A がありました: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58621271/5989200

### 推測の過程

今回の問題では複数の箇所でエラーが出ていますが、出ているエラーはどれも `ActionView::Template::Error: 783: unexpected token at ''` です。つまり、色々な view の処理に失敗している原因はどれも同じ可能性があります。

この推測のもとエラーのスタックトレースと view のプログラムを突き合わせると、javascript_pack_tag が使われている行でエラーが出ています。

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

javascript_pack_tag は webpacker を使うためのメソッドです。Webpacker は動的にファイルを変換したりキャッシュしたりする仕組みを持っており、CI 環境などのまっさらな環境で実行したときのみエラーが起こるという挙動に関連している可能性は高そうです。

そこで `webpacker ActionView::Template::Error: 783: unexpected token at ''` で検索したところ、先人の知恵を見つけ、この回答を投稿するに至りました。

テストの実行の仕方や実際のテストに使われているソースコードが具体的に質問文に書かれていたため、比較的素早く原因らしきものを見つけることができました。ありがとうございます。